# Qual é o equivalente para a cláusula Handler em C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Estou a seguir este [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeOSCJvXO1c) para tentar fazer com que o Skype automaticamente aceite perdidos de amizade. O tutorial está em VB e eu tenho de traduzir código para C# o problema é quando eu cheguei a parte de *handler*, eu tentei traduzir o seguinte código:

```
Private Sub auoAdd(uName As Skype4comlib.user) Handles Skype1.UserAuthorizationRequestReceived

End Sub
```

Neste [site](http://converter.telerik.com/) ele ignora a cláusula `Handles`, alguém sabe como se escreve a parte do handler acima para C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O C# funciona de forma diferente se comparado ao VB.NET. Adicione o seguinte na inicialização da sua classe:

```
Skype1.UserAuthorizationRequestReceived += auoAdd;
```

Onde `auoAdd` é o método que ao evento ser disparado, ele executará e `Skype1.UserAuthorizationRequestReceived`é o evento. O equivalente a isso no VB.NET é a instrução `AddHandler`.

O método `auoAdd` ficará desta forma:

```
public void auoAdd(uName As Skype4comlib.user)
{
    // Seu código
}
```